# Updating strings with multiple items

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

So I have a string that displays name of the item + quantity + price and it is appended to JTextfield container.

For example

```
Bath towel 3 5.5
Gorilla suit 3 30.0
Whizz games console 3 50.0
```

if someone now adds 1 bath towel again it will look like:

```
Bath towel 3 5.5
Gorilla suit 3 30.0
Whizz games console 3 50.0
Bath towel 1 5.5
```

and instead of that I would want to update the first line to Bath Towel 4 5.5 instead of adding below and I'm not sure how to achieve that I was thinking about adding array that I would display and update everytime someone clicks add

Here is the code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    int amountInt = (Integer)amount.getValue();
    String item = stocksDropdown.getSelectedItem().toString();
    double price = getPriceForName(item);
    String orderItem;
    if(ae.getSource() == add){
        if(amountInt>0){
            orderItem = item+" "+Integer.toString(amountInt)+" "+price+"\n";
            order.append(orderItem);
        }else if(amountInt == 0){

            //delete from array
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE stock code:

```
public class StockData {

    public static class Item {

        Item(String n, double p, int q) {
            name = n;
            price = p;
            quantity = q;
        }

        // get methods
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        public int getQuantity() {
            return quantity;
        }

        // instance variables 
        private final String name;
        private final double price;
        private int quantity;
    }

    private final static Map<String, Item> stock = new HashMap();

    static {

        stock.put("00", new Item("Bath towel", 5.50, 10));
        stock.put("11", new Item("Plebney light", 20.00, 5));
        stock.put("22", new Item("Gorilla suit", 30.00, 7));
        stock.put("33", new Item("Whizz games console", 50.00, 8));
        stock.put("44", new Item("Oven", 200.00, 4));
    }
    public static Map<String, Item> getStock() {
        return stock;
       }
    public static String getName(String key) {
        Item item = stock.get(key);
        if (item == null) {
            return null; // null means no such item
        } else {
            return item.getName();
        }
    }

    public static double getPrice(String key) {
        Item item = stock.get(key);
        if (item == null) {
            return -1.0; // negative price means no such item
        } else {
            return item.getPrice();
        }
    }

    public static int getQuantity(String key) {
        Item item = stock.get(key);
        if (item == null) {
            return -1; // negative quantity means no such item
        } else {
            return item.getQuantity();
        }
    }

    public static void update(String key, int extra) {
        Item item = stock.get(key);
        if (item != null) {
            item.quantity += extra;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Use a `JTable` or `JList`, see [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more details.  If you MUST use a `JTextArea`, then you will need to replace the current content with the updated values, don't bother trying to "inject" the changes, it's not worth the effort

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you for response! I will take a look I don't have to use JTextArea I have never done something like that in Java so wasn't really sure what would be a sensible way to go about it.

Comment: You probably want to create a class (perhaps "ShoppingCartItem") that contains the item name, quantity ordered, and price. Then create a collection of them - perhaps a HashMap with the name as the key. Then when the user requests a new item, find if that key exists in the collection. If it does, get the instance, and add to the number ordered. If it doesn't exist, create a new instance and add it to the map.

Comment: @FredK I've added more code you could guide me a bit more now

Comment: *"UPDATE stock code:"*  For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, instead of String manipulation on a high level, you should redesign your appilcation.
Keeping all that data in Strings is a really fragile, complicated and dangerous move.

Use a class for the products you use.
Keep your data within the objects.
Update the relavant object after a GUI interaction.

And only once all that is done, you can compile all the data, and write it to a JTextArea or a JList or a JTable.

Comment: Yeah it's still a bit complicated. I'll post you an example of how you can do it easily, using a HashSet and a specialized Item.

Answer (score 0):

This is the example code. It's all contained in one file.
In your project you should put each top-level class into its own file, for clarity.

**BE REMINDED** that this object handling is only for single instance classes. In the unlikely event when you want to add/remove cart items on a *multi-instance application*, you should clone Items or use factory methods or copy construtors to make sure your item stats are not mixed up with other buying customers.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.MutableComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.event.ListDataEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListDataListener;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

/**
 * This is a tool class I'd keep in a library, useful to re-use.
 * @author JayC667
 * @param <T> Class type of Items to be contained
 */
class ArrayListModel<T> implements MutableComboBoxModel<T> {

    private final List<T>                       mData;
    private final ArrayList<ListDataListener>   mListeners  = new ArrayList<>();

    private T                                   mSelectedItem;

    public ArrayListModel() {
        mData = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public ArrayListModel(final List<T> pList) {
        mData = pList;
    }

    public ArrayListModel(final Collection<T> pCollection) {
        this();
        mData.addAll(pCollection);
    }

    public ArrayListModel(final Iterable<T> pIterable) {
        this();
        for (final T t : pIterable) {
            mData.add(t);
        }
    }

    @SafeVarargs public ArrayListModel(final T... pItemsArray) {
        this();
        for (final T t : pItemsArray) {
            mData.add(t);
        }
    }

    public void fireDataChangedEvent() {
        final ListDataEvent e = new ListDataEvent(this, ListDataEvent.CONTENTS_CHANGED, 0, getSize());
        for (final ListDataListener l : mListeners) {
            l.contentsChanged(e);
        }
    }

    @Override public int getSize() {
        return mData.size();
    }
    @Override public T getElementAt(final int pIndex) {
        return mData.get(pIndex);
    }
    @Override public void addListDataListener(final ListDataListener pL) {
        System.out.println("ArrayListModel.addListDataListener() " + pL);
        mListeners.add(pL);
    }
    @Override public void removeListDataListener(final ListDataListener pL) {
        System.out.println("ArrayListModel.removeListDataListener() " + pL);
        mListeners.remove(pL);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") @Override public void setSelectedItem(final Object pAnItem) {
        System.out.println("ArrayListModel.setSelectedItem()");
        mSelectedItem = (T) pAnItem;
    }
    @Override public Object getSelectedItem() {
        System.out.println("ArrayListModel.getSelectedItem()");
        return mSelectedItem;
    }
    @Override public void addElement(final T pItem) {
        mData.add(pItem);
    }
    @Override public void removeElement(final Object pObj) {
        mData.remove(pObj);
    }
    @Override public void insertElementAt(final T pItem, final int pIndex) {
        mData.add(pIndex, pItem);
    }
    @Override public void removeElementAt(final int pIndex) {
        mData.remove(pIndex);
    }

}



class Item {
    public final String mName;          // as these are final, you can make em public with no worries
    public final int    mPriceCents;
    private int         mQuantity;      // NOT final, use getters and setters!

    public Item(final String pName, final int pPriceCents) {
        mName = pName;
        mPriceCents = pPriceCents;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return mQuantity;
    }
    public void setQuantity(final int pQuantity) {
        mQuantity = pQuantity;
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
        return mName;
    }

// equals and hashCode are needed for the hashmap/set; 
@Override public boolean equals(final Object pObj) {
    if (!(pObj instanceof Item)) return false;
    final Item o = (Item) pObj;
    return mName.equals(o.mName) && mPriceCents == o.mPriceCents;
}
@Override public int hashCode() {
    return mName.hashCode() + mPriceCents;
}

}



class OrderPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 6667651987287570825L;

    static private void flattenComponent(final JComponent pComponent) {
        pComponent.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(pComponent.getMaximumSize().height, pComponent.getPreferredSize().width));
    }

    private final JComboBox<Item>   gLstItems;
    private final JTextField        gTxtName;
    private final JTextField        gTxtPrice;
    private final JTextField        gTxtQuantity;

    private final Market            mMarket;

    public OrderPanel(final Market pMarket) {
        mMarket = pMarket;
        setBorder(new TitledBorder("Order Panel"));
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        add(new JLabel("Select Product"));
        gLstItems = new JComboBox<>(mMarket.getStockModel());
        flattenComponent(gLstItems);
        gLstItems.addActionListener((PActionEvent) -> loadItemToGUI());
        add(gLstItems);

        add(new JLabel("Product Name"));
        add(gTxtName = new JTextField());
        flattenComponent(gTxtName);
        gTxtName.setEditable(false);

        add(new JLabel("Product Price"));
        add(gTxtPrice = new JTextField());
        flattenComponent(gTxtPrice);
        gTxtPrice.setEditable(false);

        add(new JLabel("Order Quantity"));
        add(gTxtQuantity = new JTextField());
        flattenComponent(gTxtQuantity);

        final JButton orderButton = new JButton("Add to Cart");
        orderButton.addActionListener((pEvent) -> addSelectedItemToCart());
        add(orderButton);

        add(Box.createVerticalGlue());

        for (final Component c : getComponents()) {
            final JComponent cc = (JComponent) c;
            cc.setAlignmentX(0);
        }
    }


    private void loadItemToGUI() {
        final Item i = (Item) gLstItems.getSelectedItem();
        if (i == null) return;
        gTxtName.setText(i.mName);
        gTxtPrice.setText("" + (float) i.mPriceCents / 100);
        gTxtQuantity.setText("0");
    }

    private void addSelectedItemToCart() {
        try {
            final Item item = (Item) gLstItems.getSelectedItem();
            if (item == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("No item selected!");

            final int addQuantity = Integer.parseInt(gTxtQuantity.getText());
            final int newQuantity = Math.max(item.getQuantity() + addQuantity, 0); // prevent sub-selling
            item.setQuantity(newQuantity);
            mMarket.updateCart(item);

        } catch (final Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error: " + e, "Adding to cart", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}



class CartPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 7199745180760941548L;

    private final JTable        gTable;

    protected final Market      mMarket;

    public CartPanel(final Market pMarket) {
        mMarket = pMarket;

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        gTable = new JTable(mMarket.getCartModel());
        add(new JScrollPane(gTable));

        setBorder(new TitledBorder("Shopping Cart"));
    }
}



class ShoppingCartTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1536498413051546662L;

    private final HashSet<Item> mShoppingCart;

    public ShoppingCartTableModel(final HashSet<Item> pShoppingCart) {
        mShoppingCart = pShoppingCart;
    }

    @Override public Object getValueAt(final int pRowIndex, final int pColumnIndex) {
        try {
            final Item item = (Item) mShoppingCart.toArray()[pRowIndex];
            switch (pColumnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    return item.mName;
                case 1:
                    return new Float((float) item.mPriceCents / 100);
                case 2:
                    return Integer.valueOf(item.getQuantity());
                default:
                    System.out.println("CartPanel.CartPanel(...).new AbstractTableModel() {...}.getValueAt()");
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Bad index! Wrong amount of columns!");
            }
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "[]";
        }
    }
    @Override public String getColumnName(final int pColumnIndex) {
        switch (pColumnIndex) {
            case 0:
                return "Name";
            case 1:
                return "Price";
            case 2:
                return "Quantity";
            default:
                System.out.println("CartPanel.CartPanel(...).new AbstractTableModel() {...}.getColumnName()");
                throw new IllegalStateException("Bad index! Wrong amount of columns!");
        }
    }
    @Override public int getRowCount() {
        if (mShoppingCart == null) return 0;
        return mShoppingCart.size();
    }
    @Override public int getColumnCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}



class MarketGUI extends JFrame {
    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 65473329699793884L;

    private final Market        mMarket;

    public MarketGUI(final Market pMarket) {
        mMarket = pMarket;

        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Da Thrift Shop");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        add(new OrderPanel(mMarket), BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(new CartPanel(mMarket), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}



public class Market {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Market m = new Market();
        new MarketGUI(m);
    }

    private final ArrayList<Item>           mStock          = new ArrayList<>();
    private final HashSet<Item>             mShoppingCart   = new HashSet<>();
    private final ArrayListModel<Item>      mStockModel;
    private final ShoppingCartTableModel    mCartModel;

    public Market() {
        mStock.add(new Item("Bath towel", 550));
        mStock.add(new Item("Plebney light", 2000));
        mStock.add(new Item("Gorilla suit", 3000));
        mStock.add(new Item("Whizz games console", 5500));
        mStock.add(new Item("Oven", 20000));

        mStockModel = new ArrayListModel<>(mStock);
        mStockModel.fireDataChangedEvent();
        mCartModel = new ShoppingCartTableModel(mShoppingCart);
    }

    public void updateCart(final Item pItem) {
        if (pItem.getQuantity() < 1) mShoppingCart.remove(pItem);
        else mShoppingCart.add(pItem);
        mCartModel.fireTableDataChanged();
    }
    public ArrayList<Item> getStock() {
        return mStock;
    }
    public HashSet<Item> getShoppingCart() {
        return mShoppingCart;
    }

    public ArrayListModel<Item> getStockModel() {
        return mStockModel;
    }
    public ShoppingCartTableModel getCartModel() {
        return mCartModel;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please please please update your hashcode and equals methods to be correct. This objects hashcode SHOULD NOT BE THE SAME as the string.  Only reason this works is due to your equals logic... for instance myItem:{name:"myItem", price:300} is not the same as myItem{name:"myItem", price:400} hashing on the string name is wrong.

Comment: Wow yeah I actually missed that 1. Will be corrected ASAP

Comment: On the other hand... who would have two items with the same name ;-P

Comment: its not correct to have "myItem".hashcode() == new Item("myItem").hashcode()

Comment: Why not? Comparator/Comparable is a Generic, so Objects can't get messed up. I could not imagine a situation where "myItem".hashcode() == new Item("myItem").hashcode() would pose a problem.